# drop down list width change depending on the content

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the width of a drop down list depending on the content by using javascript.

Example see amazon's drop down list in the first page in search section. http://www.amazon.com/ref=gno_logo

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon uses another `<span>` element overlayed on top of the `<select>` which has its content changed to fit the `select` menu's value - and it uses `width: auto` on this tag to fit it to its contents.

So in effect, the drop-down list in Amazon is hidden while a "fake" drop-down in the form of a separate `span` takes its place.